# Change color of 3D text Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently have a light/dark mode for the website I'm making. When the toggle switch is clicked I change the body background from light to dark or vise versa, along with the mesh colors. The problem I'm facing is I can't seem to change the font color of 3D text. The 3D text was built following [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=curve#webgl_modifier_curve).

Here is my code, using vanilla javascript:

```
//curves and 3d text
    const initialPoints = [
        { x: 28, y: -5, z: -28 },
        { x: 28, y: -5, z: 28 },
        { x: -28, y: -5, z: 28 },
        { x: -28, y: -5, z: -28 },
    ];
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 );
    const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    for ( const handlePos of initialPoints ) {

        const handle = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, boxMaterial );
        handle.position.copy( handlePos );
        curveHandles.push( handle );
        scene.add( handle );

    }

    const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(
        curveHandles.map( ( handle ) => handle.position )
    );
    curve.curveType = 'centripetal';
    curve.closed = true;

    const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
    const line = new THREE.LineLoop(
        new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points ),
        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } )
    );

    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load( './../font/FONT.json', function ( font ) {

        const geometry = new TextGeometry( 'john jacobs', {
            font: font,
            size: 10,
            height: 0.05,
            curveSegments: 12,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 0.02,
            bevelSize: 1,
            bevelOffset: 0,
            bevelSegments: 5,
        } );

        geometry.rotateX( Math.PI );
        geometry.rotateY( Math.PI );


        const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
            color: 0xffffff
        } );

        const objectToCurve = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )

        flow = new Flow( objectToCurve );
        flow.updateCurve( 0, curve );
        scene.add( flow.object3D );

    } );
//curves and 3d text


const dark_button = document.getElementById('mode1');
dark_button.addEventListener("click", darkMode);
function darkMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0c1424";
    sphere.material.color.setHex( 0x0000ff )
}

const light_button = document.getElementById('mode2');
light_button.addEventListener("click", lightMode);
function lightMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    document.body.style.color = "#000000"
    sphere.material.color.setHex( 0xffffff )
}
```

On the button click, both the document background and the sphere mesh change colors.

When I try

```
objectToCurve.material.color = "0xffffff";
```

or

```
objectToCurve.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
```

The 3D text stays its initial 0xffffff white color.

How can I get the color of the 3D text to change?

Comment: Are you calling renderer.render(yourScene, yourCamera) after changing the colors?

Comment: I'm calling it inside my main animate() function which should suffice @LeFede

Answer (score 0):

```
// Inside your lightMode function
function lightMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    document.body.style.color = "#000000";
    sphere.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);

    // Create a new material for the 3D text
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    });

    // Update the material of the objectToCurve mesh
    objectToCurve.material = newMaterial;
}
```

then in your dark mode your dark mode:

```
// Inside your darkMode function
function darkMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0c1424";
    sphere.material.color.setHex(0x0000ff);

    // Create a new material for the 3D text
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    });

    // Update the material of the objectToCurve mesh
    objectToCurve.material = newMaterial;
}
```

By creating a new material and updating the objectToCurve mesh's material, you should be able to change the color of the 3D text when switching between light and dark modes.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Your response seems logical, but unfortunately that did not work.